# Changing the positon of sign in and create account from header to footer

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, custom-theme, caching, default.xml

I have created a custom theme which has parent theme as luma. Created a folder default.xml inside the theme_name_folder/layout_folder. Trying the change the code but its not reflecting in the theme. For every change do I have to run the command like php bin/magento setup:upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below line in app/Design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="header.links" destination="footer_links" after="-"/>
```

If you change any of xml file and your cache is enabled then you must have to run below command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I used cache flush too Now create account option is removed automatically

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I place the signin link in footer from the header